# Passing off other people's accomplishments as one's own

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that expresses that someone claims other people's accomplishments as their own?

> A: "So, you remember how Craig claimed to have found the bug in the software? I know for a fact that it was Paul who found and fixed it!"
>   B: "Oh well, it's not the first time that Craig ____."

The german language has the idiom "to adorn oneself with borrowed plumes" or "to adorn oneself with someone else's plumes" - isn't there something similar in the english language?

Comment: To *steal someone's thunder* is a nice phrase, as in "Oh well, it's not the first time that Craig has stolen Paul's thunder." I don't think it quite fits, or I would post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the word "appropriate" for this:

> **[appropriate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appropriate)** (v):  *Take (something) for one's own use, typically without the owner's permission.*

However this use feels more *appropriate* (pun intended) for things like artwork, musical compositions, inventions, etc. -- things with some material value.

> The greedy Renaissance art school master was known to **appropriate** the works of his more talented students, so he could sell them at a higher price under his own name.

If you just tell people you were responsible for something when it was actually someone else, the verb is "to take credit for".

> It was well known that the powerful politician would invariably **take credit for** his administration's successes, even when it was one of his staff who actually did the work.

Side note:  There are many expressions for the opposite of this, to put the blame for your own mistakes on someone else.  One of these is "to pass off".

> However this politician (who shall remain nameless) always **passed off** failures as the fault of underlings, even when he himself was responsible.