# A word for a person who takes credit for others' work

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for a word to describe a person who always steals credit of others and always hails himself/herself as the best.

Rulers of countries are generally portrayed with such a character. They have a fragile ego too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing off other people's accomplishments as one's own](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143625/passing-off-other-peoples-accomplishments-as-ones-own)

Comment: There isn't a single word that combines all of these character traits.  Someone who fraudulently passes off the work of others as their own can be called a plagiarist. As for the other character traits, perhaps egotist or narcissist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That duplicate is asking for a word describing the act the person in this question does, not a word describing the person.

Comment: @ColleenV: The accepted *verb* answer there trivially generates the "agent" noun **appropriator**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which is not a good description of the person described in this question, and the way your proposed duplicate question is posed is unlikely to lead to answers that would also work for this question. It’s not a good dupe target in my opinion. *I quit my job because my boss was a narcissistic appropriator.* isn’t how people would normally phrase it.

Comment: @ColleenV: Each to their own, but I see no special reason to prefer ***narcissistic egotist*** over *I quit my job because my boss was a **narcissistic appropriator*** (and in both cases the OP has to apply standard morphological rules to toggle between adjectives and nouns). Whatever - the question as framed here is far too vague for us to be arguing about which term best conveys OP's *exact* intended meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then you should’ve voted to close it as needing more detail. I’m not arguing about how to answer this question. I’m telling you that’s not a good dupe target.

Comment: [Much the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300985/someone-who-takes-credit-for-others-work) (without the bizarre / confusing "fragile ego" qualification) was asked on ELU years ago and summarily closed. What makes this one so special?

Comment: [credit-stealer (boss)](https://hbr.org/2015/04/how-to-respond-when-someone-takes-credit-for-your-work)

Comment: I got to know (from the discussion), that there is no single word to describe such a person. Nonetheless, thanks for all the answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the particular context (e.g. formal/informal, neutral/derogatory, etc.), audience, and desired point of emphasis, words that might be considered include:

- plagiarist
- copycat
- narcissist
- fraudster
- swindler
- perjurer
- deceiver
- cheater
- intellectual-property thief
- pirate
- imposter
- charlatan
- pretender
- hypocrite
- shammer
- poser
- masker / masquer
- imitator
- mimic
- con-man / con artist

Check the dictionary of your choice for the specific nuance of each of these to find the best fit for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't include the idea of "stealing credit," but you could call such a person **egotistical,** [defined by MW as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egotistical)

> having, showing, or arising from an exaggerated sense of self-importance